# R - require clarification on whats happening with the code

Tags: r

The details of the problem is listed here in this [link](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33996_08e0ccbe7be64a32a7a4501e549a5492.html)

I couldn't not understand whats happening in the following lines of code:

```
Elite=rep("No",nrow(college))
Elite[college$Top10perc >50]=" Yes"
Elite=as.factor(Elite)
college=data.frame(college ,Elite)
```

I understand the line 2 and 3, but the rest seems to be mystery. I would really appreciate any help on this subject.

Thanks,

Yogi

Comment: Which function are you unclear about? You can bring up the help pages for any of these functions By typing `?rep` in R (for example). I assume you can also run each line individually to see what is happening. It would help to ask a more specific question.

Comment: I was not clear about whats each of these lines were doing. I didnt try the ? thingy on R. I will do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the included comments clarify your questions?

```
#Create a vector of "No" of length equal to the number of rows in the dataframe college
Elite=rep("No",nrow(college))

#Subset the vector with the conditions of the column Top10perc > 50
#in the dataframe college and then set values to "YES"
Elite[college$Top10perc >50]=" Yes"

#Turn the Yes/No character strings into factors
Elite=as.factor(Elite)

#column bind the original dataframe with the newly created vector
#to update the original dataframe college.
college=data.frame(college ,Elite)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

I would like to clarify the following:

1. Elite is a totally independent vector with the dimension [1xnrow(college)]. All the value of the vector is "No". Correct?

Comment: Yes,  it is an independent vector.  The value of every element in the vector is No